# What will happen if I get GTA V from Steam and use the code on an account with GTA V Social Club Edition on it?

Tags: steam, pc, grand-theft-auto-v, grand-theft-auto-online

I bought GTA V from Rockstar Warehouse, but now I regret that decision. Will I keep my save data / online users if I use the code I get from Steam to activate on my current rockstar account? Also what will happen about the achievements? Will I keep my online character?

Comment: Also if you wonder why I regret: 1) people keep asking me where I pirated Gta V when they see it is off-steam. Explaining that it isn't pirated takes longer than loading gta online. 2) I collect games and have all gta games, including the not-obtainable-anymore gta 1 and 2.

Comment: I believe you should be able to assign your current RSC account to your steam account once you buy the game and use the gta v key for RSC on a separate account, thus having a fresh non-steam gta account and your current gta account would work with steam. I'm too lazy right now to find confirmation for this, so I'm posting this as a comment, instead of an answer :P

Comment: To elaborate - when you launch the game from steam, it logs you into Rockstar Social Club and the first time you have to sign in with your existing credentials or create a new account. This RSC account is then attached to your steam profile and can't be used with any other Steam profile.

Comment: @Chippies afaik, steam codes have a special thingy saying "Access to Gta V on Steam" or something.

Comment: @Chippies yeah, I have mine connected to mine, yet I didn't allow nor set this. I saw it on profile a time back.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that, because the steam key and the RSC keys are separate and you get both when you buy from steam (steam key automatically redeemed, obviously). You can download the launcher from Rockstar Warehouse and completely bypass steam with the steam version, as it is the same game.

Comment: What you're thinking of is the social accounts on your profile. That can be unlinked at any time and serves no practical purpose. What I was talking about is actually linking the GTA V key to your steam account, so it won't be able to be used with a different steam account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you link your current Rockstar Social Club (RSC) account to your steam version of GTA V, you will keep your online characters, profile and friends, as all that is saved to your RSC account.

Your offline mode save files are saved on your computer, so they should stay as available as well. Your achievements most likely won't get transferred to Steam, but they will remain on the RSC account.

You won't actually have to redeem your key on RSC account, since you can just log onto your existing account when you first run the game from steam, so you will have a spare key to activate on a different account, that will be non-steam.

Comment: 10$ for steam edition if I sell the r* code, eh? Thanks for the help, will try and report asap. (asap is a few weeks actually)